# Remote file access using java on Windows

Tags: java, jsp, sharing, remote-access

I'm developing an application using struts that can read .txt files from a remote system. I cant figure out how to do that. Could someone please suggest some example where it is explained how to enter the URL?? Its on http. Thanks.

Comment: There are so many ways to access remote file, 1. FTP/SFTP, 2. Writting a servlet that will serve the file from local FS to remote client..etc.. what you would implement?

Comment: url of what - the remote location?  what is on http - your application or the remote .txt files?

Comment: the url is http://10.176.158.12:8080/c:/test.txt
That is what i want to know. How to specify the URL. An example implementing the entire thing using http would be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Let me try and make it clearer. I have two systems. Both have Apache Tomcat deployed on them. I want to be able to read a text file on system from another system. I have found a couple of examples to read the file if it is inside the folder deployed by tomcat, but how to use the absolute paths?? As in a url like I mentioned above?? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Here you need add copy file program which will copy file from c:/abc/abc.txt to your web project folder
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.demo.com/abc.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The above code would work if I wanted to get files on a website. Could you please mention the format of the URL if I want to get it from lets say this location : C:/demo/abc.txt

Comment: In this case , you need to have program, which will first a fall copy file  C:/demo/abc.txt to your webapp/project directory. and using above program you can read that. Ref http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/copyfile.shtml

Comment: I have added comment part in URLReadr program, where you need to write logic to copy file